# Vanilla CSS in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a react app for the first time and I'm not sure what the right way to style your components is.
Next to each component or page I create a file with the .css extension and use it implicitly because I feel like this way is the easiest but there are some drawbacks obviously so I don't know if it's considered a bad practice.
Is it better to use styled components/css modules or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: There's no right answer here; both have benefits and drawbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say pick one that suits you best.

I used both styled components and vanilla CSS(with BEM) and I think that both are worth to try, but there are some differences.

For example, if you want to use some variables across all components (like theme etc.) than in styled components you need to use ThemeProvider and than consume it with function like:

```
const FancyDiv = styled.div`
    background: ${props => props.theme.colors.main)``;
```

But in vanilla you need to import css file in every components css file,
for example in scss:

```
// src/components/fancyDiv/styles.scss

@import '../../styles/settings.scss';

.fancyDiv {
    background: $main-color;
}
```

Another difference comes when you want to change style of element based on props/state etc.
Lets consider an example that we want to style a link in the navigation based on state which tells if link is active or not.

```
const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
```

With styled components

```
const FancyLink = styled.a`
    color: ${props => props.isActive ? 'red' : 'green'}`;

<FancyLink href="#aboutme" isActive={isActive}>About me</FancyLink>
```

With VanillaCSS

```
.nav__link--active {
    color: 'red';
}

<a href="#aboutme" className=`nav-link ${isActive ? 'nav__link--active' : ''}`>About me</a>
```

As you can see both of them will fit most of use cases but in a bit different way.